# polling for progress on long running process in asp.net/angularjs

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asynchronous

I have an oldish asp.net website I've been slowly refactoring to use angularjs. One of my pages calls a very long running process that I want to keep the user informed about progress, and also to keep their session active.

I thought I could achieve this by using some angularjs such as the following:

```
    $scope.setupLongRunningProcess= function() {
        $scope.progress = {};
        $scope.result = null;

        startLongRunningProcess();

        $timeout(function () {
            pollProgress();
        }, 5000);
    }

   function pollProgress() {
        if (!$scope.result) {
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "MyPage.aspx/PollProgressJson",
                data: {}
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.progress.Count = response.data.d;

                $timeout(function() {
                        pollProgress();
                }, 5000);
            });
        }
    }

    function startLongRunningProcess() {
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "MyPage.aspx/LongRunningProcessJson",
            data: {}
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.result = response.data.d;
        });
    }
```

It starts out OK, calling startLongRunningProcess() which calls MyPage.aspx/LongRunningProcessJson, and then calls pollProgress() as expected. However, it never gets to MyPage.aspx/PollProgressJson on the server. The long running processs on the server is just a usual WebMethod:

```
<WebMethod>
Public Shared Function LongRunningProcessJson(...) As Result(Of String)
    Dim service As LongRunningProcessService = GetService...
    Return service.LongRunningProcess(..., HttpContext.Current.Session)
End Function
```

Here I was using the Http Session to put in a count of progress, and all PollProgressJson is doing is querying that.

I didn't want my original call to LongRunningProcessJson to finish until it is complete, so should I be making an async call in there to do all the work (and wait until it is finished before returning)?

Or, am I taking completely the wrong approach? (and yes, I know, I don't like passing in a Session object to my business layer, it does feel very icky)

I've also tried making the LongRunningProcessJson WebMethod Async, but the PollProgressJson does not get called:

```
<WebMethod>
Public Shared Async Function LongRunningProcessJson(...) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Result(Of String))
    Dim service As LongRunningProcessService = GetService...
    Return Await Task.Run(Function() service.LongRunningProcess(..., HttpContext.Current.Session))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that Asp.Net pages queue requests (by holding a session lock) that *may* be writing to the same Session and this can only be turned off at the page level (unless of course your entire web app doesn't need it), not at the WebMethod level. So solution was to add:

```
<%@ Page .... EnableSessionState="ReadOnly" ...." %>
```

to my page directive, and remove use of Session to write the progress to (I didn't like doing that anyway). Instead you could use the database, global variable (yuk) or file to store&query your interim progress.

Note: I believe in MVC you can do the same thing at the Controller-level by adding the attribute:

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $q service notify() function to check the progress status. Details are here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q